# cqlengine: way to create nested map

Tags: python, cassandra, cqlengine

In what ways we can create a nested map in [cqlengine](https://github.com/cqlengine/cqlengine) models, For e.g

```
class Test(Model):
     id = columns.UUID(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
     address = columns.Map(key_type, value_type)
```

I want "value_type"(in address [column](https://cqlengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/models.html#columns)) to be a dictionary again, how should we achieve this using cqlengine data modelling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible in the current Cassandra release. Container columns can't contain other containers. In C* 2.1 (unreleased), this should be achievable using user defined types, although cqlengine support will lag behind the C* release a little.

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql-in-2-1